# Customize UINavigationBar in IOS without using UINavigationController setting background image not working

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

I am newbie for IOS. So I have tried to customize the UINavigationBar with out using navigation controller. I have able to change the tile and background color but I have tried to setting the background image programmatically its not working.whether its possible to set background image using story board itself ? I have tried may websites in that mostly used programmatically. so any possible way to set the background image using UIStoryboard ?

Comment: can you show ur code

Comment: I have used swift.. which I have to show??

Comment: let navBackgroundImage:UIImage! = UIImage(named: "Navbar-background-fitted") self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(navBackgroundImage, forBarMetrics: .Default)  @Anbu

Comment: we can't directly change in story board

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can do like

[image]

and you get the output of

[image]

**Note**

if you load the Image from Assests use like `UIImage(named: "xx")`

```
if let img = UIImage(named: "xx")
{
    self.topBar.setBackgroundImage( img , forBarMetrics: .Default)
 }
```

else if you load the Image from resource bundle   use like `UIImage(named: "xx.extenson (.png )")`

```
 if let img = UIImage(named: "xx.jpg")
{
    self.topBar.setBackgroundImage( img , forBarMetrics: .Default)
 }
```

you can check with this function in [apple douments](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UINavigationBar.html)

[image]

here I attached [the sample Project link Download and check once](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xux7ajql5szoh59/test.zip?dl=0)

Comment: I have tried.. same problem not showing background image.but color has changed.

Comment: @vara - I upload the sample project check once

Comment: Ya Your sample project working fine. landscape portrait it not showing. I have tried in load image in Assets.

Comment: @vara - I dont know ur concept of project I just solved based on your question

Comment: Thanks.. Its working fine. if I have load the image in resource bundle.

Comment: @vara - happy to hear

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
[yourNavigationbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"YourBackgroundImage.png"] 
               forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

For **Swift**

```
yourNavigationbar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "YourBackgroundImage.png"),
               forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

Comment: let navBackgroundImage:UIImage! = UIImage(named: "Navbar-background-fitted")      self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(navBackgroundImage, forBarMetrics: .Default)

I have tried.. but its not working